# NSMutableDictionary returning incorrect value with accent words

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get the string from xml
 NSData *xmlData = [request responseData];

```
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

loginParsingDelegate *loginResultParser = [[loginParsingDelegate alloc] init];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
[parser setDelegate:loginResultParser];
[parser parse];

 NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/conf.plist", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] ;
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   NSString *city = [parsingResult objectForKey:@"city"];
```

but when have accent, this get wrong...example:
  Sao Paulo  = "Sao Paulo "but São Paulo I'm getting "ão Paulo"

what's wrong? The xml is returning correct...

Comment: Your snippet is irrelevant to the problem. Could you show your parsing code?

Comment: How is this data being viewed? Are you logging the dictionary? Displaying it in the UI? Looking in the debugger?

Comment: NSString *city = [parsingResult objectForKey:@"city"];

Comment: What is `parsingResult` and where is it used?

Answer (score 4):

I've launched your code with a simple XML string

```
<city>São Paulo</city>
```

Looks like you are not handling characters properly in your delegate. For this XML `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` is actually called twice: first time with "S" and second time with "ão Paulo". You should handle such situations since this method is not guaranteed to provide you a full string in one shot anyway.

> parser:foundCharacters:
>
> Sent by a parser object to provide its delegate with a string
>   representing all or **part** of the characters of the current element.

**UPDATE:**

An extremely simple example. Given an XML

```
<cities>
    <city>São Paulo</city>
    <city>Rio de Janeiro</city>
    <city>Salvador</city>
</cities>
```

we can make a parser like this

```
@implementation ParserClass {
    NSMutableString *elementText;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    elementText = nil; // we are not handling elements other than "city"
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"]) {
        elementText = [NSMutableString new]; // prepare an empty string for city name
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [elementText appendString:string]; // append new characters to the element text
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    // element did end - string now contains text of the element
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"]) {
        NSString *cityName = [elementText copy]; // now we have a full city name
        ...
    }
}

...

@end
```

Note that this is *not* a generic code to parse any XML. You could write one of course if you have an understanding of how SAX parsing works.

Comment: first I received S but not in "cidade"

Comment: if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"cidade"])
    {
        
        appDelegate.cidade = string;
    }

Comment: How can I do this that you say?